# Mercurial Client with SVN Support for Windows

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, integration

Are there any Mercurial clients for Windows that have integrated SVN support? Our build server uses SVN and there are no plans to move towards Mercurial, but I prefer Mercurial over the other distributed source control clients I have tried (e.g., Git).

I've looked into [TortiseHG](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home) and the [Mercurial homepage](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/), neither of which seem to integrate with SVN, despite the fact that the the [Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) seems to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[hgsubversion](http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/overview/) looks like a good bet to me. See this [blog post](http://blog.red-bean.com/sussman/?p=116) and the discussion in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826938/interoperation-between-mercurial-and-subversion). Basic usage notes are [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion).