# Can I use Mercurial locally, and update from/push to a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

As a freelancer, I often work at companies who use Subversion repositories.

It’d be handy if I could use Mercurial to get code from these repositories, track my changes when I’m offline, and then commit all my local changes to the company’s Subversion server when I’m back online.

Does this work? Have you read any good tutorials on the specifics?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799860/using-mercurial-locally-only-with-subversion-server. I reckon my question should stay around too though; this is one of those questions that can be worded in quite a few different ways.

Comment: Aaaand this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826938/interoperation-between-mercurial-and-subversion

Comment: Here’s the same question on Kiln Overflow, or whatever it’s called: http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/948/can-i-use-mercurial-locally-and-update-from-push-to-a-subversion-repository/950#950

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [HgSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion). It allows you to do just that. You can clone a (part of) svn repository locally to an hg repository and work with hg locally and svn remotely (push and pull do what you would expect of them).

I have used it with some success in the past but do not have extensive experience with it.

Answer (score 8):

I'm working at a company that is using CVS, so HgSubversion wasn't an option. I had the same question a few days ago and developed a workflow based on this:

http://momentaryfascinations.com/programming/how.to.use.mercurial.for.local.source.code.management.with.a.public.subversion.server.html

I created a Mercurial repository where my CVS repository is, which I treat as "readonly". I then clone this "readonly" hg repo to working repositories, where I make changes/fixes locally. I have been cloning the repo for every feature and fix that I make, but you could also just have one repo, and use a different branching strategy to manage your development. Here's [a good overview](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/) of such strategies.

The key to this workflow is having that "readonly" repository. I used to make my changes in the first Mercurial repository I created, which was on top of CVS. This worked, but it got confusing when updating from CVS. By having this additional layer, you can deal with making your own changes and updating from CVS separately.

**Keeping in sync with CVS**

Whenever there are changes in CVS, I do a cvs update. To the "readonly" hg repository, this will show up as modified files. To sync up Mercurial, I simply do a

```
hg ci -m "Updated from CVS."
```

(So, you'll see a lot of those messages in my hg logs). At this point, my "readonly" repository is sync'ed with CVS. Now I can go to any of the repositories I've cloned and issue a `hg pull` and then `hg update` to sync them up.

**Committing changes from hg back to CVS**

Going the other direction, when I want to commit to CVS, I'll go into one of my working repositories where I've committed my changes already to hg. Then I `hg push` my changes back to "readonly", hop over to the "readonly" repository, do an `hg update`. From CVS's perspective, this will appear as freshly modified. I then do a `cvs commit` back into CVS. Here I'll have to repeat/summarize in my log message the work that I've done in my hg repository.

Admittedly, there are rough spots in this workflow. You could be making multiple changes in hg, which add up to just one change in CVS/SVN, so that history will not be kept in CVS/SVN, and you'll have to summarize your commit messages. You have to manually manage keeping CVS and your "readonly" repository in sync. The advantage of this is that you don't need to install any additional extensions - you are just dealing with the files themselves from both perspectives. Everything that is happening is pretty transparent and under your control.

I'm still cutting my teeth on hg, but so far this workflow has been working out reasonably well.

[Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47078/harvey) has provided a nice diagram of this and makes an excellent point that this workflow applies to any other VCS:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sr105.com](http://sr105.com/other_vcs_to_hg_workflow.png))</sub>

Comment: @bentsai: This is a good explanation of probably the most basic way to use mercurial with *any* other VCS. Good for consultants. It needs a diagram.

Comment: Diagram you could put into your answer: http://sr105.com/other_vcs_to_hg_workflow.png

Comment: The only problem I can see with this approach is that you won't have the CVS history in your Mercurial repository, so you'll have to be careful when looking back through changes. That may be acceptable though in a large number of cases.

Comment: @Harvey: The diagram is now a broken link, any chance it can be updated?

Answer (score 2):

You can find some info on this [wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion).